# Taking Solr 6.1.0 to production

Tags: solr, solr6

We'd like to create a simple search engine with Solr. It seems to be pretty complicated. I mean it's easy to use example configurations to make some simple indexing/searching. But what we need is to make a redistributable server with simple configuration and without all the crab which comes with solr-6.1.0.zip.

Which are necessary files (I guess at least bin- and server-folders)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would want to use the Docker image at

https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/

Still complicated, but there is a 'How to use this Docker image' to get you going.